# Image won't center with android:layout_centerHorizontal

Tags: android-layout, android-xml

my image wont center using the code "android:layout_centerHorizontal" even using gravity wont solve it. Is there any other way or are there wrong inputs in my relativelayout and scroll view.

[scale layout bounds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlpCk.png) 
[landscape view of with scale layout bounds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPID1.png)
screen size 768x1280 nexus api23

I am not having problems with android version 4 maybe this is api related? since my minimum sdk is android version 2?

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.capstone.jmilibraryapp.Login">


<EditText
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etUsername"
    android:hint="Enter Sr-Code"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
<ImageView
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:src="@drawable/jmilogo"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etPassword"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etUsername"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bLogin"
    android:text="Log In"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etPassword"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etPassword"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etPassword" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Log In as Guest"
    android:id="@+id/guest"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bLogin"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Log In as Guest"
    android:id="@+id/testinguser"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/guest"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   />


</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: what you want ?? i mean you want to put you imageview behind the EditText ??

Comment: @uttampanchasara sir I have added an image sorry for the late reply I have slow internet connection at home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your image don´t have the same ratio of your ImageView, you can check it enabling showLayoutBounds in the developer tools in the device. You will see the real size of the imageView.

To solve that you can make you ImageView to be proportionally to your ImageView or ad a scaleType="fitCenter" to your ImageView.

Comment: yeah probably should i change any image size? i have updated my post by the way maybe i am having a problem with api versions?

Comment: @earlcabanig remove 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" from your ImageView. It is overriding the centerHorizontal behavior.

Comment: this is the answer, I voted up but can seem to publicly see the score due to my reputation is below 15. Thanks by the way ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try below xml this is work with me..

[image: Outout]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/school" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etUsername"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:hint="Enter Sr-Code" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etPassword"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/etUsername"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bLogin"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etPassword"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etPassword"
                android:layout_below="@+id/etPassword"
                android:text="Log In" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/guest"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bLogin"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Log In as Guest"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/testinguser"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/guest"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Log In as Guest"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: sir I tried your code and I get this error " java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.capstone.jmilibraryapp/com.capstone.jmilibraryapp.Login}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)" maybe Im having problem with appcompactview?

Comment: try to use suport library 7 ur using older version